# Function that updates function documentation

Tags: documentation

Could the following command be put in a function that takes a function name (`workbench`) and a variable (`workbench-usage`) containing the usage string.

```
(put 'workbench 'function-documentation
     (concat (documentation 'workbench t) workbench-usage))
```

Comment: The question isn't clear. (And there's no "following command".) You seem to be posting essentially the same question over and over, circling around what you really mean to say/ask. Please consider posting a single, clear question and deleting the quasi-duplicates. Thx.

Comment: Thought one needs to ask a different question for a different thing, rather than continuing in comments?  Just using the same code.

Comment: Tho question is about how to pass a function name and a string as arguments to another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Th[e] question is about how to pass a function name and a string as arguments to another function.

The same thing we do every night, Pinky:

```lisp
(defun append-to-documentation (a-function-name some-extra-documentation)
  (put a-function-name 'function-documentation
       (concat (documentation a-function-name t)
               some-extra-documentation)))
```

Then you could call it like this:

```lisp
(append-to-documentation 'workbench "some extra documentation to be appended")
```

Easy.

This is not a very good kind of question, because it doesn’t really help anyone else; you can always replace any subexpression with a variable. (Well, there are some tricky situations with quoting that commonly trip people up.)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(concat (documentation a-function-name t)`

Comment: Yes. I was just… uh… making sure that you were paying attention.